# socket.socket() no argument is TCP or UDP

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

Saw the following example online and I'm wondering if this is using TCP or UDP protocol

```
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('localhost', 12345))
server_socket.listen(5)
```

Comment: The `listen()` tells you it must be TCP.

Comment: in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket) you can see default values `socket.socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None)` - `SOCK_STREAM` means `TCP`